# Get selected TableRows original index in TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview

Is there any way to get the original index of the selected row in TableView before the TableView was sorted or filtered? If not, can I alternatively make my own TableRow object, get it when selected and have a method getOriginalRowIdex() ?

The code `tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());` returns the selected index according to the sorted and filtered data, which makes matching the row indexes to the indexes in a list not possible.

```
 tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<ObservableList> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (!row.isEmpty())) {
                   label.setText(rowMessages.get(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()));

                    System.out.println(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());

                }
            });
            return row;
        });
```

Comment: For what purpose do you need to resolve the original index? Normally everything you need should be stored alongside your model element, that is being displayed in the TableView so you dont have to do additional lookups.

Comment: I don't use a model as the data is added dynamically(from database). I have a message that should be unique for each row.

Comment: I have a message that should be unique for each row, and I store all the messages in a list of strings. If I have the original row index I can just do list.get(originalIndex)

Comment: I'm of course open to suggestions, but this is the best solution I've found.

Comment: You could wrap the Object you get from the Database and store the message there. Then you have everything bundled up and dont have to do error-prone index lookups.

Comment: The only problem is that I talk to data in columns instead of rows, but can you still do it with your method ?

Comment: I can not see any of that in your question..

Comment: @eckig Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65584/discussion-between-minihessel-and-eckig).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FilteredList` and `SortedList` are just wrappers around a regular `ObservableList`.  Since you have to have the original list, just look up the index of the data in the row using `list.indexOf()`.

```
public class FilteredTable extends Application {
public static void main(String[] args){launch(args);}
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ObservableList<LineItem> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0;i<10;i++){items.add(new LineItem(i+"'th", i));}

        TableView tableView = new TableView();
        FilteredList<LineItem> evens = new FilteredList<>(items, p->p.amountProperty().get()%2==0);
        SortedList<LineItem> sorted = new SortedList<>(evens);
        sorted.comparatorProperty().bind(tableView.comparatorProperty());
        tableView.setItems(sorted);

        TableColumn<LineItem,String> descCol = new TableColumn<>("desc");
        descCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("desc"));

        TableColumn<LineItem, Double> amountCol = new TableColumn<>("amount");
        amountCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("amount"));

        Label label = new Label("click a row");
        tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<ObservableList> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (!row.isEmpty())) {
                   label.setText(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()
                           +" <-tbl row, idx in items-> "
                           +items.indexOf(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()));
                }
            });
            return row;
        });

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(descCol,amountCol);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(5,tableView,label),300,300));
        stage.show();
    }


    public class LineItem {

        private final StringProperty desc = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final IntegerProperty amount = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public StringProperty descProperty() {return desc;}
        public IntegerProperty amountProperty() {return amount;}

        public LineItem(String dsc, int amt) {
            desc.set(dsc); amount.set(amt);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Or maybe leverage the `getSourceIndex(int)` methods for Filtered/Sorted Lists.